# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) requirejs+karma

Tags: requirejs, mocha.js, karma-runner, chai

I am facing issue to load test file from another directory to my unit test file. i am using requirejs and karma another question is it right way to load chai-http module in test scenario file project

```
|--service
     |--abcfile.js // i want to use method implemented in this file and
                      test it.  
 |---node_modules
   -- all node library like karma,chai module

  |--test-main
     |--test-main.js    
| karma.conf.js
```

Karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['mocha', 'requirejs'],
    files: [
      {pattern: 'node_modules/**/*.js', included: false},   
      { pattern: 'node_modules/**/*/*.js', included: false },
      'test/test-main/test-main.js',
      { pattern: 'test/test-main/*.js', included: false }

    ],
    exclude: [

    ],

    reporters: ['progress','html'],

    htmlReporter: {
      outputFile: 'test/report/units.html',
      pageTitle: 'Tests',
      subPageTitle: 'A sample project description'
    },  

    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    captureTimeout: 60000,
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

test-main

```
(function() {

  var specFiles = null;
  var baseUrl = '';
  var requirejsCallback = null;
  if (typeof window != 'undefined' && window.__karma__ != undefined) {

    baseUrl = '/base';
    requirejsCallback = window.__karma__.start;
    specFiles = [];
    for (var file in window.__karma__.files) {
      if (window.__karma__.files.hasOwnProperty(file)) {
          if (/.*\/javascript\/*\/.+_Test\.js$/.test(file)) {
          specFiles.push(file);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  requirejs.config({
      baseUrl: baseUrl,

      paths: {

        'chai': './node_modules/chai/chai',
        'sinon': './node_modules/sinon/pkg/sinon',
        'chaiHttp': './node_modules/chai-http/dist/chai-http',
      },

      deps: specFiles,
      callback: requirejsCallback
  });
})();
```

user test scenario file

```
define(function (chai, sinon, chaiHttp) {

    var expect = chai.expect;
    var service= require('/service/abcfile.js');// this is file where i want one of the function to test
    chai.use(chaiHttp);
```

Error
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @Louis i have edited./service/abcfile.js is not under node_module. it is under root directory. if i put module then i have to include in  test-main file to add that module right like paths: {
        'service': '/service/abcfile',
        'chai': './node_modules/chai/chai',
        'sinon': './node_modules/sinon/pkg/sinon',
        'chaiHttp': './node_modules/chai-http/dist/chai-http',
      },

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the CommonJS sugar you have to define your module using `define(function(require, exports, module) {...` and it looks to me that the path of the module currently failing should be `service/abcfile`' (no `.js` extension needed or desirable, and no leading slash). So something like this:

```
define(function(require, exports, module) {

    var chai = require("chai");
    var sinon = require("sinon");
    var chaiHttp = require("chaiHttp");

    var expect = chai.expect;
    var service= require('service/abcfile');// this is file where i want one of the function to test
    chai.use(chaiHttp);
```

You could omit `exports` and `module` from the callback passed to `define` if you end up not using them.

Comment: i have edited./service/abcfile.js is not under node_module. it is under root directory. if i put module then i have to change test-main file to add that module

Comment: Oh boy! I had a mistake in my earlier version due to careless editing. I've edited my answer to fix my mistake and take into account your comment.

Comment: i have edited./service/abcfile.js is not under node_module. it is under root directory. if i put module then i have to include in  test-main file to add that module right like paths: {
        'service': '/service/abcfile',
        'chai': './node_modules/chai/chai',
        'sinon': './node_modules/sinon/pkg/sinon',
        'chaiHttp': './node_modules/chai-http/dist/chai-http',
      },

Comment: You're not telling me anything I don't already know. With my last edit, requirejs should issue a query to karma's server with the path `/base/service/abcfile.js` note how there's no `node_module` in there.

Comment: after changin karma.js:87 Error: Module name "/service/abcfile" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded

Comment: adding dependency manually like abcfile.js is using node-rest-client module, node-rest-client again it depends on negotiator module i have to define like it and on and on

Comment: <pre> <code> define(function (require, exports, module) {var chai = require("chai");var sinon = require("sinon");
var chaiHttp = require("chaiHttp");var expect = chai.expect;
var httputil = require('util/HttpUtil');var service = require('service/abcfile);// application src js file. want write test case for one of its functionvar Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;var client = new Client();var negotiator = require('negotiator/lib/negotiator');chai.use(chaiHttp);
});